# SQL SERVER: TOP 10 rows per field - if less than 10 rows then display empty rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select TOP 10 ACCT rows based on SYS_CD value. Hence i wrote the below query. The query working fine.

```
SELECT SYS_CD, ACCT, CNTACCT ,rowid
FROM
  ( SELECT SYS_CD, ACCT, COUNT(ACCT) AS CNTACCT,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SYS_CD
                              ORDER BY COUNT(ACCT) DESC
                             )
             AS rowid
    FROM [FCIDIAL].[dbo].table1
    WHERE ERR_CD != 'Y'

     GROUP BY SYS_CD, ACCT
  ) tmp
WHERE rowid <= 10
ORDER BY SYS_CD, rowid, ACCT;
```

It providing the below result

```
SYS_CD FIN_AAAT    CNTFIN_AAAT rowid
AAA     606000          4        1
AAA     566000          3            2
AAA     503200          1            3
BBB     251260      42433978         1
BBB     400601      41181797         2
BBB     400401      8399908          3
BBB     503200      2087703          4
BBB     604000      40795        5
BBB     130039      4748             6
BBB     252000      655              7
BBB     736000      40               8
BBB     735000      38               9
BBB     734000      36               10
CCC     233210      73611         1
CCC     464250      39397             2
CCC     186020      35231             3
CCC     265155      4949              4
```

The query result also correct.

But my expected output is, for a SYS_CD if the rowid is less than 10 then display blank rows for the remaining rows.

Example: In the above 'AAA' present with only 3 rowids. So i need to display 7 blank rows.
'BBB'is present with 10 rowids.  So no need of blank rows.
'CCC' is present with 4 rowids, so i need to display 6 blank rows.

I expect the below output.

```
SYS_CD ACCT        CNTACCT        rowid
AAA     606000          4        1
AAA     566000          3            2
AAA     503200          1            3
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row 
BBB     251260      42433978         1
BBB     400601      41181797         2
BBB     400401      8399908          3
BBB     503200      2087703          4
BBB     604000      40795        5
BBB     130039      4748             6
BBB     252000      655              7
BBB     736000      40               8
BBB     735000      38               9
BBB     734000      36               10
CCC     233210      73611         1
CCC     464250      39397             2
CCC     186020      35231             3
CCC     265155      4949              4
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row 
                    - Blank Row
```

How i can achieve this desired result.

Comment: You need to use a numbers or tally table for this. Effectively the base of your query needs to be a table with 10 rows, then left join to the rest of your results.

Comment: what is the destination reporting system/application? it would be easier to do it there than sql, but Sean is right if you want a SQL only solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get all your values for `SYS_CD`, and table of numbers from 1 - 10:

```
SELECT  ccd.SYS_CD, n.RowID
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT SYS_CD FROM [FCIDIAL].[dbo].table1 WHERE ERR_CD != 'Y') AS ccd
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) AS n (RowID);
```

Once you have this you can `LEFT JOIN` back to your original query, so you will end up with `NULL` for missing records:

```
WITH tmp AS
(   SELECT  SYS_CD, 
            ACCT, 
            COUNT(ACCT) AS CNTACCT,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SYS_CD ORDER BY COUNT(ACCT) DESC) AS rowid
    FROM    [FCIDIAL].[dbo].table1
    WHERE   ERR_CD != 'Y'
    GROUP BY SYS_CD, ACCT
) 
SELECT  ccd.SYS_CD, tmp.ACCT, tmp.CNTACCT, n.RowID
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT SYS_CD FROM [FCIDIAL].[dbo].table1 WHERE ERR_CD != 'Y') AS ccd
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) AS n (RowID)
        LEFT JOIN tmp
            ON tmp.SYS_CD = ccd.SYS_CD
            AND tmp.rowid = n.RowID
ORDER BY ccd.Sys_CD, n.RowID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an existing tally table you can generate one for this on the fly pretty easily. This should work assuming you are on 2008+.

```
with MyData as
(
    SELECT SYS_CD
        , ACCT
        , COUNT(ACCT) AS CNTACCT
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SYS_CD ORDER BY COUNT(ACCT) DESC) AS rowid
    FROM [FCIDIAL].[dbo].table1
    WHERE ERR_CD != 'Y'
    GROUP BY SYS_CD
        , ACCT
)

select *
from (Values(1),(2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)) n(x)
left join MyData d on d.rowid = n.x
order by d.SYS_CD, n.x
```

Comment: Now that I posted this it will get the correct rows but you won't be able to order it correctly because the value of d.SYS_CD will be NULL for every row that doesn't have all 10.